# How to add Triples to graph for further query in customed builtin primitives?

Tags: jena, jena-rules

i'v tried this code

```
Triple t = NodeFactory.createURI(s,p,o);
context.add(t);
```

However, I cannot get this triple using sparql.

Comment: Hi there - we'd need some more information so we can see what your application is doing. What have you tried to make a SPARQL query on "context"? This may help:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask .

Comment: Thanks, but I think I've solved this problem. The node_uri should be created using http:// form other than <http://> form.